# Regarding the functionality of struts 2 interceptor and servlets filter

Tags: struts2

I have a query since I have recently started exploring struts 2 , But please advise that in struts 2 we have interceptors and in servlet's we have filter which also do the same task.Then whats the need of interceptor in struts 2 , what the difference between both.

Answer (score 1):

You took the concept in other way.Struts2 use Filter to intercept each and every request being given to framework.

Filters"  are a part of the Servlet Specification; in other words, they are part of the Servlet API.

`interceptors` are a part of the Struts 2 framework, and are only part of requests handling that is done by the STruts 2 framework.If you are using Struts 2, you should user interceptors for wrapping functionality around your Struts 2 actions.

In Short interceptors are set of reusable component which can be used at various places.Struts2 has created set of interceptors to handle some common tasks being there for each Action request like Data transfer,data conversion,validation etc.

Comment: "nterceptors are set of reusable component" - nice point :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Few differences that I can think of:

- [Filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) are part of Java EE, Interceptors are part of Struts.
- Filter cannot be action specific rather they are URL specific(which can mean Action Specific at times), they can be mapped only to Servlet.
- Filers are more for deployer (though developers also use them but if deployer has sufficient knowledge they can change during deployment time), deployer can choose configure which Filters are to be invoked for which request, whereas Interceptors are for developers, they decide how to add logic before, after action is executed.
- [Method filtering](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/interceptors.html#Interceptors-MethodFiltering) is not available in Filters but is possible in Interceptors.
- You cannot use Interceptors if you are not handling request by Struts framework say you use a Servlet to handle a specific request.

Edit: Moved comment as part of answer:

Interceptors as a pattern are not Specific to Struts2 and is available in Spring, Hibernate e.t.c

Comment: Just to add one point `Interceptors` are not specific to Struts2.this is a general concept and its available in spring,hibernate and many other platforms.On all really good explanation

Comment: Filters are mappable to any URL, whether it's a servlet or not (re: second point). Not sure what you mean by filters being for deployers; *some* filters might be general enough that a non-dev would be able to configure it, but filters also have before/after functionality, they're written by devs, and almost always would need to be specified by devs.

Comment: clarified, intent was to say deployer can change them if they have knowledge what filter do or things like that, made it clear though

Comment: @mprabhat Interceptors follows command design pattern add to your answer for better understanding.